# Set a ListMoveChange filter when using OptaPlanner Spring Boot starter

Tags: spring-boot, optaplanner

We are using the OptaPlanner Spring Boot starter to create a vehicle routing problem solver based on the example in the OptaPlanner quickstarts:

https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/vehicle-routing

So we do not have an solveConfig.xml file. We would like to define a filter for `ListChangeMove`s but it's not clear how we would register this without using an XML file. We have tried using a solverConfig.xml e.g.

```
<localSearch>
  <unionMoveSelector>
    <listChangeMoveSelector>
      <filterClass>my.filter.Class</filterClass>
    </listChangeMoveSelector>
  </unionMoveSelector>
</localSearch>
```

But this is not working. Is there an example of setting up a filter for list moves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a XML solver config using a a swap move selector and a change move selector with move filtering:

```xml
  <constructionHeuristic/>
  <localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>
      <changeMoveSelector>
        <filterClass>org.acme.vehiclerouting.solver.ChangeMoveSelectorFilter</filterClass>
      </changeMoveSelector>
      <swapMoveSelector/>
    </unionMoveSelector>
  </localSearch>
```

If you don't want to use swap moves, then you don't need the union move selector and the configuration can be simplified to:

```xml
  <constructionHeuristic/>
  <localSearch>
    <changeMoveSelector>
      <filterClass>org.acme.vehiclerouting.solver.ChangeMoveSelectorFilter</filterClass>
    </changeMoveSelector>
  </localSearch>
```

A few comments:

- I'm including the CH phase because it is necessary in a typical case. See [OptaPlanner terminates immediately if I add constructionHeuristic config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725135/optaplanner-terminates-immediately-if-i-add-constructionheuristic-config/42815082#42815082) for an explanation.
- The `ChangeMoveSelector` is automatically configured to produce `ListChangeMove`s if the planning entity has a `@PlanningListVariable`. There is no `<listChangeMoveSelector>` config element.
- More information including how to implement the move selection filter can be found in the [documentation](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html#filteredMoveSelection).

### UPDATE: No XML configuration

It's possible to inject `SolverConfig`, modify it and then use it to create other objects, for example `Solver`, `SolverManager`, and `ScoreManager`.

The code would look something like this:

```java
@Component
class MyService {

    // Don't inject these.
    private final SolverManager<VrpSolution, Long> solverManager;
    private final ScoreManager<VrpSolution, HardSoftScore> scoreManager;

    // But inject the SolverConfig.
    public MyService(SolverConfig solverConfig) {
        // And instantiate SolverManager and ScoreManager manually.
        this.solverManager = SolverManager.<VrpSolution, Long>create(
            solverConfig.withPhaseList(Arrays.asList(
                new ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig(),
                new LocalSearchPhaseConfig().withMoveSelectorConfig(
                        new ChangeMoveSelectorConfig()
                                .withFilterClass(MyFilter.class)))));
        this.scoreManager = ScoreManager.create(SolverFactory.create(solverConfig));
    }
}
```

Pros:

- `SolverConfig` will be initialized by `OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration` (from `optaplanner-spring-boot-starter`) before it's injected into your component. That means:
- The solution and entity classes will be auto-discovered and you don't have to specify them (which you have to in `solverConfig.xml`).
- You can use `application.properties` to do minor solver config tweaks, for example set time-spent termination.

Cons:

- You have to create `Solver`,`SolverManager`, and `ScoreManager` instances manually. Specifically, you can't have a `@Bean` method producing an instance of one of the types above because that would deactivate `OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration`, which creates the `SolverConfig` bean.

Comment: yurloc I tried your no xml config with version 8.33 and the solver does nothing in the LS steps.  Even if I removed the withFilterClass() and basically have vanilla classes and config after the CH step there nothing happening in the LS step there's no log output (I'm on DEBUG).  If I remove your suggested config then I get the normal output.  Any ideas why this manual config isn't working? Thanks