# OptaPlanner - Configuring a move selection filter programmatically

Tags: java, optaplanner

Is there a way of programmatically configuring a move selection filter?

https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html#filteredMoveSelection

I have a SpringBoot application that configures OP programmatically such as setting the termination config. I would like to tell OP to use a move selection filter without having to resort to an XML file as described in the documentation above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be specific. Describe what you are trying to accomplish, your goal - we can then discuss the correct means to accomplish it.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický question updated as requested. Thanks.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický Would this be what I am looking for (Java code example)? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72184672/811108

Answer (score 4):

There is a direct 1-to-1 mapping between the solver config XML, and `SolverConfig`. If you can already set termination config, you can set anything else.

Specifically, from the solver config, you can reach the phase config list. In there, find the local search phase config. And finally in there, find the selector which you want to filter, and set the filter.

It is possible that, by default, the phase config list will be empty. OptaPlanner would normally automatically add construction heuristics and local search at runtime. If that is the case, you will need to add these phases to the config list explicitly, incl. the selector configs.

As you yourself pointed out in the comments above, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72174372/set-a-listmovechange-filter-when-using-optaplanner-spring-boot-starter/72184672#72184672) probably gives you everything, incl. a code sample.

Comment: +1 But there is an open issue that neither Spring nor Quarkus can configure a SolverConfigConfigurator, something that can take the default SolverConfig created from the classpath info (entity classes etc already filled in), but allows us to enrich it programmatically (for example based on application.properties) with for example move selector configuration.